# Maven test module

Tags: java, maven

I'm running project with structure which suppose runtime modules (or plugins however you call it), like C-style .so objects. For now it works only via `ClassLoader`, and I'm trying to use maven to test it. I wrote `Test.java` and `TestModule.java` files in my project's test directory. But maven tries to run both of them instead only `Test.java`. How can I specify test files?

P.S. Is there any system for loading modules except `ClassLoader`? And new foreign modules must be the projects depends on my core project?

Comment: Maven searches test classes in src/main/test but you can customize it. Nevertheless, it is simpler to follow the standard maven structure (see Mortiz Petersen's answer)

Comment: I have no much time to check if it works, and to continue my project, so I'll accept it but check it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven - as any other build system - needs to distinguish between production and test code. The recommended variant is to separate both classes using the directory structure:

```
/src
  /main
    /java
      -- your production classes go here
  /test
    /java
      -- your test classes go here
```

If your project has a different structure, you can [change](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Directories) the default behavior in the `pom.xml` file (not recommended):

```xml
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>
  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/bin</outputDirectory>
  <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/test-bin</testOutputDirectory>
  ...
</build>
```

If you put both, production and test code in the same directory (not good, not good), you can tell Maven to [include or exclude](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) classes from running tests:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>Test.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You still need some kind of naming convention to identify the test classes (recommended: for class `MyClass` the corresponding test class should be called `MyClassTest`):

```xml
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
      </includes>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maven uses the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) to run tests. Therefor it executes the [test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) 
goal.

The [includes](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) property defines what classes will be seen as test classes. The default name pattern is:

```
<includes>
 <include>**/Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

So if you do not want a test to be executed during the maven test phase (maybe because you only want to run this test manually) than change the `includes` property or rename your class (e.g. CheckModule instead of TestModule).

If your `TestModule.java` is application code and not some kind of test code than do not place it in the test directory. Have a look at the [Maven default directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and use it if somehow possible.